# Get record for each type with latest / bigger dates in C# DBML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dbml

I have a DB table which has some data as follows:

```
LINE | QTY | USERID | DATE
-----------------------------------------
   1 |   5 |  qb1   | 2015-03-02 11:23:25
   2 |   1 |  qb2   | 2015-03-02 18:24:03
   3 |   3 |  ch1   | 2015-03-03 05:38:49
   1 |   2 |  qb1   | 2015-03-03 08:47:02
   2 |   4 |  qb2   | 2015-03-03 14:01:31
   3 |   2 |  ch1   | 2015-03-03 21:11:53
   1 |   4 |  qb1   | 2015-03-04 09:34:04
   2 |   5 |  qb2   | 2015-03-04 15:29:27
   3 |   1 |  ch1   | 2015-03-04 19:28:33
```

As you can see I have only 3 unique `LINE` values in the DB. I require a LINQ query to select the latest record of every line. The date can be any date, I just need the latest status of the lines based on "DATE" field.

At the moment I am doing it very roughly something like this:

```
var line1 = db.GetTable<lnk_sts>().Where(x=> x.LINE== 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.DATE).FirstOrDefault();
```

Same for the other 2. What I Require is a list of `lnk_sts` with only the ones with a bigger date, in this case:

```
LINE | QTY | USERID | DATE
---------------------------------------
   1 |   4 |  qb1   | 2015-03-04 09:34:04
   2 |   5 |  qb2   | 2015-03-04 15:29:27
   3 |   1 |  ch1   | 2015-03-04 19:28:33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is, group on Line and then take the first item in group after ordering in descending.

```
db.GetTable<lnk_sts>()
  .GroupBy(x=>x.LINE)
  .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(o=>o.DATE).FirstOrDefault())       
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First group by the line, then order by date and take the last item.

```
var result = db.GetTable<lnk_sts>().GroupBy(x=> x.LINE).Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).Last())
```